# How to load file from external storage instead of res/raw folder

Tags: android, storage, file-handling

This is my main activity: I am trying to read file from external storage earlier i was picking it up from raw folder. Everything was fine until was picking it from raw folder, now my custom list view is empty.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    InputStream inputStream;
    //String uri;
    String[] data;
    Vector<String> contacts = new Vector<String>();
    String uri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    String location = uri+"/contacts.csv";
    //String[] contacts={"hello","world","ge","rg","e","er"};
    int j = 0;
    TextView tv1;
   /* String fileName = "contacts.csv";
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+fileName;
    File file = new File(path);

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);  */


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setText(location);
        //  inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.contacts);

        File file = new File(location);

        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
            try {
                String csvLine;
                while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    data = csvLine.split(",");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        contacts.add(new String(data[i]));
                        j++;
                    }


                }
                try {

                    ListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, contacts);
                    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
                    lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Problem", e.toString());
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: " + ex);
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file

Comment: do you get any exceptions? any logs?